# Generating an output while linking to math library

Tags: c

this is my first time posting to this forum so if I neglect any formalities or bother anyone in any way with something similar please let me know and I'll do my best to avoid doing it again!

I am trying to generate two arrays using the following code, but I am having a problem actually outputting the code. I know this is probably something very basic, but I just started using C only about two weeks ago. I'm quite sure everything is correct, but for some reason when I try to compile the code while linking the math library with `gcc static.c -lm -o static`  and then when I further ask for the output using `./static`, I am given no output and am asked for the next command. What am I doing wrong?

If this is something simple or an oversight then the odds are I am missing something conceptually and if you wouldn't mind elaborating on it I would really appreciate it. thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 100
#define pi 3.14
#include <math.h>
int main (void) {
  double x[N], f[N];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = (double)(i) / ((double)(N) - 1.0);
    f[i] = sin(2.0 * pi * x[i]);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  printf("x is %f",x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already return success and the code below will not be executed. Swap the two statements.

```
 printf("x is %f",x[i]);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Dont forget to accept answers to help others also. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your printf is *after* the return, so your code doesn't actually reach it. You need to have it before.